# The request is allowed for logged in customer

Tags: graphql, magento2

We are using Magento 2 + Graphql for an ecommerce site.

We are able to generate token.

However, when the same bearer token is used in another API call like customerCart, it throws the error "The request is allowed for logged in customer"

The exact same copy of the website works fine in a plesk Server (nginx proxying to apache). The server we have is an EC2 instance with Apache2. The only difference I could see is the different URLs and different servers. Exact same PHP version and modules.

No other logs are available in the application logs or the error logs.

Any idea?

Deployed the same copy to another server and it works

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you entered the token in the correct format.
[Token Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Le3gK.png)
[Output for the customer cart using graphql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16CMy.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The format was correct. I created a php file that prints all headers of an incoming request and sent the call to that file. The Authorization header was there. But it was empty. None of the walkthrough in stackoverflow helped, So we finally switched the web server to Nginx. 

However, it would be good to know how to fix this in Apache2

Comment: Please add the code snippet of your PHP files